# COM - C++ Invoke function return DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH

Tags: c++, windows, automation, com, ole

I'm currently trying to call an ActiveX function of a software using COM.
here is the function declaration :

```
    [
        id(0xa),
        helpcontext(0)
    ]
    HRESULT MAIN_GetVersion (
        [out] short* nStatus,
        [out] BSTR* szStatusMsg,
        [out] BSTR* szVersion
    );
```

Here is how I do it :

```
short errorCode = 0;
    BSTR errorMessageBSTR =  SysAllocString(L"test");
    BSTR versionBSTR =  SysAllocString(L"test");

    VARIANT result;
    DISPPARAMS params = {NULL, NULL, 0, 0};
    VARIANTARG args[3];
    
    //First argument : Short*
    VariantInit(&args[0]);
    args[0].vt = VT_I2 | VT_BYREF;
    args[0].piVal = &errorCode;
    //Second argument : BSTR*
    VariantInit(&args[1]);
    args[1].vt = VT_BSTR | VT_BYREF;
    args[1].pbstrVal = &errorMessageBSTR;
    //Third argument : BSTR*
    VariantInit(&args[2]);
    args[2].vt = VT_BSTR | VT_BYREF;
    args[2].pbstrVal = &versionBSTR;
    
    params.rgvarg = args;
    params.cArgs = 3;
    
    DISPID dispID;
    char szName[200];
    // Convert down to ANSI
    wchar functionName[] = L"MAIN_GetVersion";
    wchar_t* functionNamePtr = functionName;
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, functionName, -1, szName, 256, NULL, NULL);
    CheckHResult(App.pdispVal->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &functionNamePtr, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispID) ,szName , dispID);
    CheckHResult(App.pdispVal->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, &result, NULL, NULL), szName , dispID);
    /*
    return :
        DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH
            One or more of the arguments could not be coerced. The index of the first parameter with the incorrect type within rgvarg is returned in puArgErr.
    */
```

For some reason, this code don't work and return DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH. For some other reason, if I set all my VARIANT vartype's*emphasized text* to VT_EMPTY it work but I have nothing back from result VARIANT.

Is it possible the activeX implementation of the software I try to drive is wrong ?
Am I doing something wrong ?!

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes

Answer (score 0):

When building a DISPPARAMS to setup somes arg's, you need to sort them reverse order of their calls. In my case :

```
//First argument : Short*
VariantInit(&args[2]);
args[2].vt = VT_I2 | VT_BYREF;
args[2].piVal = &errorCode;
//Second argument : BSTR*
VariantInit(&args[1]);
args[1].vt = VT_BSTR | VT_BYREF;
args[1].pbstrVal = &errorMessageBSTR;
//Third argument : BSTR*
VariantInit(&args[0]);
args[0].vt = VT_BSTR | VT_BYREF;
args[0].pbstrVal = &versionBSTR;
```

The short is the last VARIANT of my VARIANT ARRAY.